# Flip an image vertically

Tags: c++, image-processing

I'm trying to flip an image vertically, after retrieving the buffer from openGL. It seems to be outputting an incorrect image with the following code:

```
const int width = 100;
const int height = width;
const int components = 3;
unsigned char pixels[width * height * components];
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
unsigned char flipPixels[width * height * components];
for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
        for (int k = 0; k < components; ++k) {
            flipPixels[i + j * width + k] = pixels[(height) * (width) - ((j+1) * width) + i + k];
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can only iterate half the height and achieve the same, but I want to implement it by going through the complete height of the image. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with the code. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how the image is stored but your indices `i` and `k` are given the same stride which is suspicious. Maybe you want `i * components` and `j * width * components`. After that, inverting vertically you should only have to change `j` to `(height - j - 1)`.

```
flipPixels[(i + j * width) * components + k] = pixels[(i + (height - 1 - j) * width) * components + k];
```

Comment: That was it! I forgot to account for the components. This had me stumped for hours. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the pixels returned by OpenGL resulten in an upside down bitmap. so I flipped them like this: but the bitmap is still flipped left to right...

```
void Flip(GLubyte* pixels, int pixelbuffersize)
{
    // basically rewrites from bottom up...
    std::vector<GLubyte> flipped_pixels(pixels, pixels+pixelbuffersize);
    auto count = flipped_pixels.size();
    std::reverse(flipped_pixels.begin(), flipped_pixels.end());

    GLubyte* buff = (reinterpret_cast<GLubyte*>(&flipped_pixels[0]));
    const void * pnewdata = (const void *)buff;
    memcpy(pixels, pnewdata, count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is more to efficient copy entire rows of pixels using `std::copy` or `memcpy`

Using C++ `std::copy`:

```
for (size_t r = 0; r < height; r++) {
    auto src = &pixels[r*components*width];
    auto dst = &flipPixels[(height - r - 1)*components*width];
    std::copy(src, src + components*width, dst);
}
```

Using C `memcpy`:

```
for (int r = 0; r < height; r++) {
    unsigned char *src = &pixels[r*components*width];
    unsigned char *dst = &flipPixels[(height - r - 1)*components*width];
    memcpy(dst, src, components*width);
}
```

*Caveat:* This assumes that you specified byte packing before
call to `glReadPixels`:

```
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

else you you may have some padding / alignment issues.